# Are there any Stackless Python like projects for other languages (Java, Lisp, Haskell, Go etc)

Tags: python, haskell, compiler-construction, lisp, interpreter

Well thats the question. Are there any projects for other languages which try to imitate what stackless python is doing for python?

Comment: The core advantage of stackless python is that it gives a way around the GIL. Outside of that its not very impressive. Since other languages don't have a GIL, doing 'what stackless python is doing for python' is not very meaningful.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what language or runtime feature /specifically/ you see stackless python providing to python? Because many languages support preemptive green threads and more, without needing imitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrew Appel wrote long time ago a book [*Compiling with Continuations*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052103311X), implemented some old version (110?) of SML/NJ (without a stack, but with garbage collected "continuation frames"), and wrote a paper [*Garbage Collection Can Be Faster Than Stack Allocation*](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.ps%E2%80%8E) (all this in the previous century).

Several papers mention *compilation* with [*continuations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) e.g. [Flanagan](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/pldi-fsdf.pdf%E2%80%8E), etc

Scheme has a continuation-related primitive [call/cc](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation).

Also, Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html), and even a chapter from J.Pitrat's book [Artificial Beings (the conscience of a conscious machine)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470611791)

And [Go Routines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines), etc..

Recent GCC gives [-fsplit-stack](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) which is quite similar (and useful notably for implementation of the [Go Language](http://golang.org/) front-end to GCC), and usable (with care) in many languages compiled by GCC (including C & C++).

[Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) is playing strange tricks with the stack (notably for [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and `call/cc`).

So I don't think that *Stackless Python* was the first of thinking of this (and implementing these ideas).

See also the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) wikipage.

<sup>PS. And of course Haskell, Erlang, Oz, ...</sup>

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the stackless compilation with lightweight concurrency, Haskell has done that from the very beginning.  IIRC the first compilation scheme for Haskell was called the *G-machine*.  Later that was replaced by the *STG-machine*.  This is actually necessary for efficient laziness, but easy concurrency and parallelism comes as an additional bonus.

Another notable language in this sector is Erlang and its bad joke imitation language Go, as well as continuation-based languages like Scheme.  Unlike Haskell they don't use an STG compilation scheme.

Answer (score 4):

Both Haskell and Erlang contain (in the standard implementation) microthreads/green threads with multi-core support, a preemptive scheduler, and some analogue of channels. The only rather unique feature of Stackless that I can think of is serialisation of threads, although you can sometimes fake it by providing a way of serializing function state.